# Implement realtime online/offline status with flutter and firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

what is the best way to show in an app if the user is online or offline?

Frontend -> Flutter

Backend -> Firestore Cloud and Firebase Auth.

I have a collection of users in Firestore that contains documents. Each document is a user and contain `status` field. In Flutter, I can update this field every time that user log in or log out but if you close the app it is not updated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can extend your statefulWidget State class with `WidgetsBindingObserver` 
like

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

and `initState` method add `WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);`.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }
```

Later overide `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed)
      //TODO: set status to online here in firestore
    else
      //TODO: set status to offline here in firestore
  }
```

Comment: Add this to the statefulWidget class that you using in main.dart file.
It will work throughout your app everytime app is RESUMED and everytime app went to background.

Comment: Is it possible to detect when the user click the view all apps icon and swipes away the app.

Comment: Hi friends, but how about web, how to make it work for web version thanks in advance!

Comment: But, if I turn off wifi and then close the app, didChangeAppLifecycleState() will try to set status to 'offline' in Firestore, but as wifi is off Firestore can't set status to offline... So, other users of the app will see that user 'online'. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Raiyan did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: @MitulAgrawal I used a different approach.

Step 1: If User-A opens the app, the app sets his `activeUntil` field to let's say: **Now + 5 minutes**.

Step 2: Define a function that is reccuring called **every 4 minutes and 55 seconds** that updates the `activeUntil` field with the **New Now + 5 minutes**

Step 3: User-B gets User-A's `activeUntil` time. If **Now < User-A's `activeUntil`**, User-B sees that User-A is online.

Step 4: If **Now == User-A's `activeUntil`** in User-B's app, it fetches User-A's **New `activeUntil`**. If there's no updated `activeUntil`, User-A is offline.

Comment: @Raiyan That's a good approach. I was also thinking about doing something like this. The only issue is that it will increase the cost in firebase. But I guess this is the only solution that'll handle the internet case.

Answer (score 2):

IT CAN DONE BY  **WidgetsBindingObserver()**;

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {...}
```

initialize it first

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
}
```

After add this function to listen for app state **didChangeAppLifecycleState()**

```
String? changes;

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

final isBg = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;
final isClosed = state == AppLifecycleState.detached;
final isScreen = state == AppLifecycleState.resumed;

isBg || isScreen == true || isClosed == false
    ? setState(() {
      // SET ONLINE
    })
    : setState(() {
      //SET  OFFLINE

    });
print('CHANGES IS : $changes ');
```

}

> **String? changes** Contains Your app State! Be Happy You Can what you want , This can notify Online status like Whatsapp Messenger!

MyCode :

```
    isBg || isScreen == true || isClosed == false
    ? setState(() {
      changes = "User is online"
    })
    : setState(() {
      changes = "User is Offline"
    });
    print('CHANGES IS : $changes ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch in onerror.

You have to chenge souce as server
**source: Source.server**

`users.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server))`

```
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      final CollectionReference users = _firestore.collection('users');
    
      users.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server))
          .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          print(doc["first_name"]);
          print(doc["last_name"]);
          print(doc["gender"]);
          print(doc["phone_number"]);
        });
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print(error.toString());//Offline
        Global.showSnackBar(context, error.toString(), false);
      });
```