# Is there a way to find out if the user is online or not in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Please I want to create an online or offline feature for users in my app

I tried onDisconnect in Firebase and it didn't work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement realtime online/offline status with flutter and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784758/implement-realtime-online-offline-status-with-flutter-and-firebase)

Comment: No, I don't want this. I want if the user disconnected the Internet, it appears to other users as offline, and if he connects to the Internet again, it appears online.

Comment: Cedric : you can help me I want if the user disconnected the Internet, it appears to other users as offline, and if he connects to the Internet again, it appears online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket.io for flutter. When user open the app then socket will tell the server that specific user is connected.The user able to see other connected users. Here is a article of [how to use socket.io in your project](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-ui-socket/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try **pusher presence channels**.
It is based on websockets, and it tells you who is connected to the channel (who is present). You can find the use cases for presence channels [here](https://blog.pusher.com/what-are-presence-channels-pusher-presence-channels-when-and-how-to-use-them/).

[click here](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels/) to find out how to build presence channels.

I'm currently building an online and offline statusbar for a flutter app if a user is connected to a presence channel. If I have the working code I'll post an update.