# How do I check if a specific user is running the app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

As an admin... I would like to know if a specific user has the app currently running on his phone.. ( It should be false if the app is running in the background )… I use firebase AUTH as a method of login in...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784758/implement-realtime-online-offline-status-with-flutter-and-firebase did it resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In your State<...> class you need to implement WidgetsBindingObserver interface and listen for widget state changes. Something like this:

[image]

Then when you want to know what is the state, check _notification.index property. _notification == null => no state changes happened, 0 - resumed, 1 - inactive, 2 - paused.