# How to know if a user is using my app (I want to know if user is online or offline)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know if a user using the app. Like WhatsApp, if true, the user is online, otherwise offline.

What I want is not to check if the application has a connection.

While I could add an `isOnline` field in Firebase Firestore, I didn't because I can only make that field true when logged in and false otherwise. If so, it will appear online, although the user closed the app, since the user is still logged in.

I've referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60784758/16124033), but it didn't help.

My code:

```
bool isOnline = ; // I need your code
```

---

```
Text(
  isOnline ? "Online" : "Offline",
  style: TextStyle(color: isOnline ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
),
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to know the user is using the application (I want to know if the user is online or offline)? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement realtime online/offline status with flutter and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784758/implement-realtime-online-offline-status-with-flutter-and-firebase)

Comment: @MendelG this question doesn't answer my question

Comment: what this sentence "user using the app" define so it's true, I mean what the user should do to be considered as online, offline ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy when user device's screen is app it means user is online else offline

Comment: I guess this can be made `WidgetsBindingObserver` like in @MendelG proposed question ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know that much about riverpod, I use Bloc

Comment: @Gwhyyy I tried that, but it didn't work. Also, it's okay

Comment: This feature is backend base, in your backend part you can check user call api and when user call any api that means they online, and after two minutes of calling last api if they don't call any api that means they are offline. also I think the social media app like WhatsApp doing this with checking connection the app with socket api. I think this two way are only ways and you can't do this in flutter part. @MyCar

Answer (score 2):

You could make it so that while the app is open the device will put the current time into a Firebase Firestore field every 15 seconds.

Then the other device that will listen to that result and check if that time is more than 30 seconds ago. You have to be really careful because the clocks of two devices that be separated by a lot of time. For this reason the comparison needs to be done Server-side (using Firebase Cloud Functions) and you need to put the server time into the field. This can be done using Firebase Firestore (basically putting in the field that the Firebase servers need to put the current server time into the field).

This is the only way to implement this feature without it breaking when the user force closes the app, since time passing is the only way to detect that. Using firebase to implement this might not be the best way, because of limitations in how Firebase Cloud Functions can work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Can you share more information? Like, some code or some documentation or other information